# ASP.net creating dynamic Radio Button List

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I need  to create dynamic radio button in my table.I have a table in default.aspx(id =table1) but in .cs I dont access to table1 this is frist problem. if I can reach it, I want to create dynamic radio button List . For example I want to create 8 radio button list which have 5 members. I think I do this with foreach block. I find this code samples :

```
foreach (?)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
    radioButton.Text = answer.Text;
    radioButton.GroupName = question.Id.ToString();
    radioButton.ID = question.Id + "_" + answer.Id;

    TableRow answerRow = new TableRow();
    TableCell answerCell = new TableCell();
    TableCell emptyCell = new TableCell();

    emptyCell.ColumnSpan = 2;

    answerCell.Controls.Add(radioButton);
    answerRow.Cells.Add(emptyCell);
    answerRow.Cells.Add(answerCell);

    table.Rows.Add(answerRow);
}
```

but I dont know actuallu.thanks for answering...

Comment: I wonder if you could show us the relevant aspx markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to create dynamic radio button in my table.I have a table in
>   default.aspx(id =table1) but in .cs I dont access to table1 this is
>   frist problem.

use `runat="server"` attribute to table:

```
<table id="table1" runat="server"">
</table>
```

From code, you can add rows and cells dynamically. For example:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
        radioButton.Text = "Text " + i.ToString();
        cell.Controls.Add(radioButton);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
    table1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: And I need to 3 radio button list which have 5 members.

Comment: if you set AutoPostback to true, it will adds javascript code to html, which automatically rises post back. So it depends on your business logic.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j <3; j++)
        {
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
              HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                RadioButtonList radioButtonList = new RadioButtonList();
                radioButtonList.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                radioButtonList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                cell.Controls.Add(radioButtonList);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
            myplace.Rows.Add(row);
        }
 this is work thanks for answering